# Нужно скопировать файлы из одной директории в другую с учетом имени пользователя

Tags: c++, winapi

Нужно скопировать файлы из одной директории в другую с учетом имени пользователя

Есть директория 1 и директория 2 и также имя пользователя Windows.
Мне нужно перенести файлы из директории 1 в директорию 2 (C:\Users\ТУТДОЛЖНОБЫТЬИМЯПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ\AppData\Roaming\Yandex\YandexDisk2) И допустим перенести на рабочий стол.

Как мне получить имя пользователя и использовать его в пути директории?

Comment: Используй `std::filesystem::rename` (*moves or renames a file or directory*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

чтобы получить имя пользователя:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587426/get-current-username-in-c-on-windows

чтобы собрать все в одно имя:

```
char username[UNLEN+1];
DWORD username_len = UNLEN+1;
::GetUserName(username, &username_len);

const std::string path = std::string("C:\\Users\\") + std::string(username) + std::string("\\AppData\\Roaming\\Yandex\\YandexDisk2");
```

ну или с юникодом:

```
WCHAR_T username[UNLEN+1];
DWORD username_len = UNLEN+1;
::GetUserName(username, &username_len);

const std::wstring path = std::wstring(L"C:\\Users\\") + std::wstring(username) + std::wstring(L"\\AppData\\Roaming\\Yandex\\YandexDisk2");
```

Comment: только везде следует использовать wchar_t

Comment: @user7860670, ну в общем-то да, добавил